# Basedir issue in Ant code

Tags: ant

I am working on some project using Apache Ant and my project layout is as follows:

```
project/build.xml
project/properties/build.properties
project/tool/antcontrib.jar
```

Here, when i run ant command it working fine and my base directory is basedir="."

Now, I want my project layout to be as follows:

```
project/folder/build.xml
project/properties/build.properties
project/tool/antcontrib.jar
```

Now, I changed my base directory to basedir="..". I thought it might work.
but still it's not working. 
So i wan't to known what we have to set our basedir for '../'
Here is the code block related to taskdef defined in my build.xml file.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${tool.ant.contrib}"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

NOTE: I known that build.xml and properties file should be in same folder its a standard practice. But i don't want to follow that..can any one help me out here...

Comment: Do you get an error message with a specific task?  If so can you post that part of the buildfile?

Comment: I am sure if basedir path is set correctly everything will work fine. But the thing is ../is not working in basedir.

Can you tell if i use .. instead of ../ is it correct !

Comment: What do you mean with "Its not working for me", what is the error? How do you call ant from which working directory?

Comment: The error was net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties not found.
I am using antcontrib.jar file.

Thanks for your help. Its working now. I made few changes in my path. I did ../../ in basedir path.

Comment: Setting ".." in basedir is working. You must tell us what is your error.

Comment: I am getting the same error as mention in the above comment! Can any one Help me out here !

Comment: Ashwin, it's not at all clear what your problem was, or is now.  Can you edit your question to state what the problem now is, what error message you get, and if possible show the buildfile? ... at the moment the comments read like you had a problem, but fixed it, but it came back ... but I can't be sure.

Comment: As i said i am using antcontrib.jar file. In my build.xml i have changed my basedir as i have said above and after running ant i got  net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties error message on cmd console. So i guess my basedir path is not matching correctly that's why its showing me the error !

Comment: I have some variable defined in the property file and that property file contents that path of the antcontrib.jar file which i am using in build.xml file. See i am changing my question. ! Provide some more details

Comment: From where are you running your ant script? from / or /project/folder/?

Comment: I am moving to the directory project/folder/ and running from there.

Comment: @iCybernetics Did you correctly defined your `${tool.ant.contrib}`? the lib also need to be in your CLASSPATH, [see here](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/)

Comment: Ok...This CLASSPATH thing need to check out. Because i have not set the tool in classpath

Answer (score 1):

In order to work, the property `tool.ant.contrib` should be a relative path, not an absolute one.

For instance, this piece of build works:

```
<project basedir="..">
    <property name="tool.ant.contrib" location="tool/antcontrib.jar" />
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${tool.ant.contrib}"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <if><isset property="tool.ant.contrib" />
        <then><echo message="OK" /></then>
    </if>
</project>
```

Comment: My location already contains relative path and not absolute par for tool.ant.contrib in attribute location

Comment: As asked in the other comments, there is something missing to solve your puzzle. Share your error and the way you set that property 'tool.ant.contrib'.